# Bash - Batch file rename

Tags: bash

I have a folder with 61 jpg's in the order Picture 002.jpg through Picture 062.jpg, I'd like to remove the "Picture" and properly rename the files 01 to 61 in the same order they're currently in. How can I do this in a bash script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

x=1
for f in *
do
    if [ "$f" != "change_name.sh" ]; then
       new_name=`printf "%02d.jpg" $x`
       mv -v "$f" $new_name
       x=$((x+1))
    fi
done
```

Usage: save the script as `change_name.sh` in the same directory of your image and run.

You can `ls` your directory before running this script. If file names are ordered correctly, that's fine. Or you may change `ls` in the `for` loop `ls|sort`.

Hope this can help.

Comment: It is bad practice to go `for f in $(ls)`, you should just use `for f in *`.

Comment: @dbaupp Could you please explain it? For efficiency? Thanks.

Comment: Efficiency (`*` doesn't fork any extra processes), and correctness (using `ls` will break if there are files with spaces or newlines in their names).

Comment: When I run this I get

mv: target '01.jpg' is not a directory
mv: target '11.jpg' is not a directory
mv: target '111.jpg' is not a directory
mv: target '1111.jpg' is not a directory
mv: target '11111.jpg' is not a directory
mv: target '111111.jpg' is not a directory
mv: target '1111111.jpg' is not a directory
mv: target '11111111.jpg' is not a directory
mv: target '111111111.jpg' is not a directory etc.

Comment: For one, you need to use `$((x+=1))` instead of just `x+=1`.

Comment: Alright, it still says it isn't a directory though, and now I also get "'x' isn't a command."

Comment: You can do `(( x+=1 ))` instead of `x=$((x+1))`